# How to use one function variables inside another function in class python

Tags: python

I've code like this

```
class salesperson:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    
    
    def buyproduct(self, product_name, market_price, quantity):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.market_price=market_price
        self.quantity=quantity
    
        return ({self.product_name: [self.market_price, self.quantity]})


    
    
    def getname(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Input:

```
sp_name=salesperson('name')
sp_name.buyproduct('mobile',30,20)
```

output:

```
{'mobile': [30, 20]}
```

Know I want to create a separate function called "getvalue" inside class & Use that variables in "buyproduct" function & want to perform so operations.

Like.

```
class salesperson:


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    
    
    def buyproduct(self, product_name, market_price, quantity):
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.market_price=market_price
        self.quantity=quantity
    
        return ({self.product_name: [self.market_price, self.quantity]})

####################################################creating new func######
    def getvalue(self):
        self.buyproduct()
        finalamount=market_price * quantity
        return finalamount
##################################################################
    
    
    def getname(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Clearly I don't know the syntax, So can you guys know the syntax/example that calls the one function inside another function with in class?

Expected input:

```
sp_name.getvalue()
```

should print

Expected output

```
600
```

Explanation: 30 * 20 = 600(From buy product function)...

Thanks in advance

Comment: finalamount = self.market_price * self.quantity.  Also, self.buyproduct() won't work because you haven't passed any parameters

Comment: You should fix your indentation, your example isn't clear which functions are inside the class.

Comment: I'm sorry, all the functions inside salesperson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just can't do it that way. The way you are supposed to do this in Python is put all the class variables in the init function. So you would do like this :

```
class Salesperson:


    def __init__(self, name, product_name, market_price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.market_price = market_price
        self.quantity = quantity
    
    def buy_product(self):
        return {self.product_name: [self.market_price, self.quantity]}

    def get_value(self):
        finalamount=self.market_price * self.quantity
        return finalamount

    def getname(self):
        print(self.name)
```

And if your problem is you sometime want to execute get_value but you dont want to give useless variables to Salesperson class, you just give name and product_name None value, like this :

```
sp_name=Salesperson(None,None,30,20)
sp_name.get_value()
```